# Aligning search bar for mobile with bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In upgrading to bootstrap 3, a lot of the layout for a site I am working on had to be repaired. I've managed to fix a great majority of it, however a final element of the page seems to be out of my grasp.

An example of what I am having issue with can be viewed below:

http://1ro.co/shopfine/template.html

As far as desktop version goes, it works fine. However if you shrink the page horizontally (to simulate it being the "mobile" version), the button goes wrong in two ways:

1. At tablet size (768px-979px), it no longer is in line with the other buttons. I'm assuming this is an obscure width issue, but I cannot seem to pinpoint it.
2. At the mobile size (<786px) the search bar and its corresponding button do not match up. Rather the button hangs to the right.

An example of what the site looked like before the move to bootstrap 3 is also below:

http://1ro.co/shopfine/account.html

I cannot figure out the issue (width?) on the tablet version, and the mobile version can't seemed to be fixed by floating any of the objects within the search bar, so in short I need to figure out in what way I can fix those two things on bootstrap 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your `input-group` class with a column size e.g.

```xml
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." id="appendedInputButton" class="form-control">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
          <i class="icon-search"></i>
        </button>
      </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Don't forget to add `form-control` class to your `input` tag.

Comment: I believe the last time I tried this, it didn't work. I'll release an attempt on both answers

Comment: This one still causes issues with the button not being attached, however. http://1ro.co/shopfine/template_2.html

Comment: This is as per the bootstrap documentation and actually worked for me when doing the changes on the fly through firebug but obviously not the same as your environment.

Comment: @Rogue there is a mistake in your code on template_2.html. Check out the class="form-control" on the input, it has spaces between it and not being applied.

Comment: I think you're looking at the wrong form. There is no `form-control` on the search bar, that's down by the newsletter signup. Edit: strange, it isn't in my IDE but it is on my page: http://pastie.org/pastes/8394115/text

Comment: I was also change your <div id="searchbar"... class="col-sm-2" to something like col-sm-4 and in the class that wraps the input group set it to col-sm-12

Comment: I'm not check it - <input id="appendedInputButton" class="form- control" type="text" placeholder="Search..."> there is a space in the class name so its not being applied.

Comment: Aha, caught it. Happened to be looking at the template_1.

Answer (score 1):

1. You have assigned the wrong class, it should be `col-sm-2` not `col-md-2` to the `div#searchBar`
2. Lose the `div.input-fields` and add the `.form-inline` class to `<form>` tag, and `.form-group` to the form elements like so:

   `<form method="get" action="page" class="siteSearch form-inline"> 
       <input type="text" id="appendedInputButton" placeholder="Search..." class="form-group"> 
       <span class="input-group-btn form-group"> 
             <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"> 
                    <i class="icon-search"></i> 
             </button> 
       </span> 
    </form>`

PS sorry about the formatting, something's not righton my end

**EDIT**

From the bootstrap documentation:

> Inputs, selects, and textareas are 100% wide by default in Bootstrap.
>   To use the inline form, you'll have to set a width on the form
>   controls used within.

So just follow the example code the [documentation page](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms), add necessary `.form-control` tags and assign widths to them.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that the button is simply pushed to an entirely new row. http://1ro.co/shopfine/template_1.html

Comment: It worked through explicitly setting the width on the form and controls, which while it was possible to do wasn't exactly desirable. Thanks for the effort though.